# Chrome v55 breaks qx.ui.form.MenuButton

Tags: qooxdoo

When I click the menu button, no menu appears.

Google Chrome just updated on my machine to the latest version (Version 55.0.2883.87 m), and after the update my qx.ui.form.MenuButton stopped working. Is there a patch or workaround for this? I'm on a Windows 7 machine.

It even fails on the demobrowser:
http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.1/demobrowser/#widget~Menu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Chrome introduced in version 55 pointer events: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/pointer-events

qooxdoo already had a pointer event layer which created artificial events for browsers not supporting pointer events natively. This layer didn't detect chromes new native pointer event support, leading to double fired ponter events, which leads to menu button menues being opened and closed right afterwards with no visible reaction to the user.

This was fixed in qooxdoo github master via PR https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/pull/9219

Please also note how this could be fixed for existing qooxdoo 5.0.1 applications: https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/issues/9182#issuecomment-265161921

Or you could use current master or patch your local copy manually using the code from https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/pull/9219

Answer (score 1):

They released a new Update since 3 Days. [Here](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/releases) you can get it.